# Flutter and Android Studio installation broken by recent update

Tags: android, flutter

I recently updated my Flutter installation because there's was a little notification in Android Studio. Now it's broken.

Whenever I try to run my app I get this error message;

`Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper`

When I check the versions of everything I get;

`Flutter 2.2.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`

`Framework • revision 02c026b03c (2 weeks ago) • 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700`

`Engine • revision 0fdb562ac8`

`Tools • Dart 2.13.1`

Gradle is version 7.0.2 and the flutter, dart and gradle plugins all seem to be installed and updated in Android Studio.
I have Java 16.0.1 and JAVA_HOME seems to be set correctly in the system variables. And the path to Flutter seems to be correct as well.

Inside the directory for my app, I also have `android\build.gradle` and `android\settings.gradle`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the solution to this was to completely remove any trace of flutter, android studio, java and gradle, and to reinstall everything from scratch. Just be aware that if you do this you may run into to problems with your code if you copy / paste it from your old app.